# Ghostscript - append merge pdf into single file

Tags: ghostscript, pdftk

I need to merge multiple pdf's into single file which I'm doing like this:

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=aio.pdf aio_single.pdf another.pdf
```

and it is working, but it is extremely slow (~5 minutes) - file `aio_single.pdf` contains almost 380 pages.

for example similar command using `pdftk` takes about ~1sec

```
pdftk aio_single.pdf another.pdf output aio.pdf
```

Is there any solution to speedup this?
I don't wan't to use any kind of compression, image manipulation and so one... Just make single file from them..

The reason I am using `ghostscript` instead of `pdftk` is that after merging files - bookmarks aren't clickable anymore :/

Comment: It seems you are asking the wrong question. If you really want to use pdftk to merge PDFs and keep the bookmarks, ask about that problem rather than your attempted solution (see also http://xyproblem.info/). Possible solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969479/merge-pdfs-with-pdftk-with-bookmarks and here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17045/how-to-preserve-bookmarks-when-rearranging-pages-of-a-pdf-file-with-tools-like-p

Comment: I've already tried this solution and it didn't work. That's why I've switched to ghostscript

Comment: Please note that other users here won't know that you tried this and that it didn't work. Make sure your question contains *all* relevant information and, in particular, shows what you've already tried and ruled out.